# "The inside of the building was beautifully decorated (...)" — translation to Latin

Tags: word-request, translation-check, sentence-translation

Sentence to translate:

> The inside of the building was beautifully decorated — such striking opposition with the ugly outside appearance.

My attempt:

> Intus aedificii decore ornatus erat — tantus flictus contra ad aspectus deforis malus.

It would be helpful if you took time to check my attempt for mistakes.
*Intus* probably is wrong — how do you say *the inside*, *an inside* (noun)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using "inside" as a preposition or an adverb, but as a noun, so *intus* is not a good choice.
I recommend the word [*interior*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=interior&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059).
(The English word "interior" is useful for this purpose, too!)
The interior of the house could be called *pars interior* or simply *interiora* (≈ "everything inside").
In your example, *interior* can be contrasted with *exterior*.

Here's one possible translation:

> *Mire decorata ornataque erat aedificii pars interior — exterior pars immo turpiter deformis.*
>   The interior of the building was wonderfully decorated and embellished — but the exterior was disgracefully ugly.

The repeated words of quality (*decorata+ornata* and *turpis+deformis*) and the chiastic word order give the comparison emphasis.
Therefore I rendered "such striking opposition" as simply *immo*.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways in which you might translate this, but I suggest *Vero pars aedificii interior in modum contra exteriorem indecorum pulcre ornata est.* This translates the sentiment of the whole sentence, but in a way more natural to Latin in various ways, including the use of word order to imply the intended effect — for which it's often unnecessary to translate every word literally : other replies may be quite different, but equally valid.

*Intus* is an adverb, 'on the inside', etc. To use it isn't exactly wrong, but the inside of anything is generally *pars interior*, the 'inner part', which in this case I've used for contrast with the outside as *(pars) exterior* (in the acc. to follow *contra*). *Vero* is placed first in the sentence to emphasise the difference.